# Variable simultaneously true and false

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

This is my code

```
class ToolDispatcherBlueprint extends Destroyable {
  _tool;
  _dispatchRegister = null;

  _state = {
    selectedTool: null,
    selectedElement: null,
    hoveredElement: null,
    keyboardKeyDown: null,
    keyboardKeyUp: null,
    mousedown: false,
    mouseup: true,
    mousemove: false
  };

  constructor(paper) {
    super();
    this._tool = new paper.Tool;

    let dispatchOnKeyDown = (event) => {
      this._state.keyboardKeyDown = event;
      this.dispatch(event);
    };

    let dispatchOnKeyUp = (event) => {
      this._state.keyboardKeyUp = event;
      this.dispatch(event);
    };

    let dispatchOnMouseDown = (event) => {
      this._state.mouseup = false;
      this._state.mousemove = false;
      this._state.mousedown = true;
      console.log("dispatcher", this._state.mousedown, this._state);
      this.dispatch(event);
 ...
```

The issue is that I get a log which indicates both that mousedown is true and false simultaneously. I expect it to indicate true and the property of `_state` to also indicate `true` ie. `_state.mousedown: true`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not what you think. When it is printed, the `true` comes through. But the object is held by reference by the dev tools. It is only evaluated when you expand the object, and by that time, your mousedown event has ended.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

The value changes not simultaneously for sure. `console.log(this._state)` outputs some snapshot of the object from the later moment.

Never rely on how objects are displayed in console. Only primitive values can be trusted. If you need to output a snapshot of the object, output its properties one by one or convert it to a primitive:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(this._state, null, 2))
```

Comment: Not always feasible but much better, yes.